# Is DSPACE(n) = DSPACE(1.5n)?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

From space-hierarchy theorem it is  known that if $f$ is space-constructible then
**DSPACE**($2f(n)$) is not equal to **DSPACE**($f(n))$.

Here, by **DSPACE**($f(n))$  I mean the class of all problems that can be solved in space $f(n)$ by a Turing machine with some fixed alphabet. This allows  to consider Space-hierarchy theorem with such accuracy.

The standard argument gives multiplicative constant $2$: we need space $f(n)$ for constructing a calculation of some Turing machine by an universal one. Also we need $f(n)$ to solve a problem with halting.

**Question:** Is **DSPACE**($f(n)$) equal to **DSPACE**($\frac{3}{2}f(n)$)?

Comment: Any reason you are interested in $\frac32$? Would $1+\Omega(1)$ be equally interesting?

Comment: Why do you think that the space-hierarchy theorem gives $2f(n)$? I suppose that you argue that we need $f(n)$ space for simulation and $\log_{|\Sigma|} |\Sigma|^{f(n)}$ space for counting the number of steps to avoid infinite loops. But in both cases we need to first mark the $f(n)$'th location on the tape (can be done since $f$ is space-constructible) and how would you do the marking? Your argument is OK if you assume that the machines are not allowed to write *'s, but otherwise some further complications are needed.

Comment: @Thomas Actually I want $1 + o(1)$

Comment: For a careful argument along these lines, see this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000077800421  In it, Seiferas fixes the number of tape symbols, and also the number of heads per tape.  Theorem U-2-D (based on Theorem 5) gets a separation by increasing the space bound by a factor of 10, not 2.  I'm not aware of anything that was published improving this bound.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be proved that **DSPACE**$(f(\frac 32 n))\ne $ **DSPACE**$(f(n))$ if $f$ grows at least linearly by using a simple variant of the standard padding argument.
For a language $L$, let $L'=\{x0^{|x|/2}\mid x\in L\}$.

**Claim.** $L\in$**DSPACE**$(f(n))$ if and only if $L'\in$**DSPACE**$(f(\frac 23n))$ if $f(n)\ge \frac 32n$.

(My first answer had several incorrect statements, thanks to Emil for spotting this.)

I will first show how to use the claim to prove the hierarchy.
Since $f$ grows at least linearly, we have **DSPACE**$(2f(n))\subset$**DSPACE**$(f(2n))$.
Take a language $L\in$**DSPACE**$(f(2n))\setminus$ **DSPACE**$(f(n))$.
Using the claim, $L'\in$**DSPACE**$(f(\frac 43 n))=$ **DSPACE**$(f(n))$, where the last equality is by the indirect assumption.
But then $L\in$**DSPACE**$(f(\frac 32 n))=$ **DSPACE**$(f(n))$, where the last equality is again by the indirect assumption, giving a contradiction.

**Proof of the claim.**
If $L'\in$**DSPACE**$(f(\frac 23 n))$, then to prove $L\in$**DSPACE**$(f(n))$, we just need to write $|x|/2$ 0's to the end of the input $x$ and simulate the machine that accepted $L'$.
Since $f(n)\ge \frac 32 n$, this won't increase the space we use.
(In fact, knowing how many 0's to write is not clear at all if $f$ is small and we cannot increase the alphabet size - instead, we can use another tape and write on that everything that would come after the end of $x$.)

The other direction is just this simple by replacing the 0's with *'s, if we are allowed to write *'s. (See the issues with this in my comment to the question.)
If we are not allowed to write stars, then we slightly modify the definition of $L'$ as $L'=\{x10^{|x|/2}\mid x\in L\}$.
Now, instead of writing stars, we keep the original input $x10^{|x|/2}$ and work with that.
But whenever we reach a 1, we go right until we hit another 1 to check whether it was the end-of-word 1 or not.
If we've found another 1, we just go back to our 1.
If we haven't, we still go back, but we'll know that it should be treated as a star - if we were to write on it, then we also write a 10 after it to have a new end-of-current-word marker.
(In fact, there's also a small catch in this part if $f$ is small - how can we check if the input is of the form $x10^{|x|/2}$? Without destroying the input, I can only solve this by using multiple heads for small $f$.)

Comment: I don’t understand the argument at all. Any way I look at it, the padding construction only shows that if $L\in\mathrm{DSPACE}(f(n))$, then $L'\in\mathrm{DSPACE}(f(\frac23n))$, which is quite different from the claim (mind the location of the $\frac23$). Likewise, the opposite direction is not clear at all as stated, what is only clear to me is that if $L'\in\mathrm{DSPACE}(f(\frac23n))$, then $L\in\mathrm{DSPACE}(f(n)+\frac n2)$. Even if I take the claim at face value, the proof of the main result is wrong: $L\in\mathrm{DSPACE}(2f(n))$ only gives $L'\in\mathrm{DSPACE}(\frac43f(n)+\frac n3))$.

Comment: @Emil You're right. I tried to fix it, does it look any better?

Comment: It’s not entirely clear to me what machine model you are using, but in the standard model with a read-only input tape whose length does not count towards the space bound, I do not see how to show $L'\in\mathrm{DSPACE}(f(\frac23n))\implies L\in\mathrm{DSPACE}(f(n))$ without at least an $O(\log n)$ space overhead. But all right, now I believe the main result, as long as $f$ is space-constructible. Actually, it should give $\mathrm{DSPACE}(f(n))\subsetneq\mathrm{DSPACE}((1+\epsilon)f(n))$ for any constant $\epsilon>0$ by iterating the argument.

Comment: @Emil I don't think the input tape is read-only - AFAIK that is only assumed if $f(n)<n$.